# I reall don't know what the problem is, form reset doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, input-field

Whenever I try to press a key - in this case m - the form reset doesn't work and one m or whatever the key is always remains in the inputfield, help

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const input = form.querySelector("input");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
input.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.key === "m"){
        console.log(`triggered`);
        input.value = ""; // or form.reset()
        console.log("form reseted")
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you get the log messages?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1):

From [Keydown MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event):

> The keydown and keyup events provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events.

You're using the keydown event trying to match a character, while you should match the keycode.

Example from working code used in one my applications (to detect the enter key pression and clear up the input field of a chat):

```
var input = document.getElementById("user-input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("sendbtn").click();
  input.value=""; // Let's reset the input value
  }
});
```

As you notice, i'm using the "keyup" event, comparing the value returned by event.KeyCode with the code of the key i want to detect (in this case 13, the keycode for "enter").

Answer (score 0):

I think that using function getElementById() is better than querySelector().
It will work well.

```
 var input = document.getElementById("user-input");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if(event.key == "m") {
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log("form reseted");
       input.value=""; 
      }
    });
```